# OData example not working (Python)

Tags: python, odata

I'm running this code that I got from here

https://tuomur-python-odata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#what-is-this

```
from odata import ODataService
url = 'http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/'
Service = ODataService(url, reflect_entities=True)
Order = Service.entities['Order']
query = Service.query(Order)
query = query.filter(Order.Name.startswith('Demo'))
query = query.order_by(Order.ShippedDate.desc())
for order in query:
    print(order.Name)
```

When I run the code, it says *ImportError: No module named odata*. I tried using *pip install odata*, nothing was found. How do I install this library? I can't find any documentation on how to install it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the project from GitHub, run *python setup.py install*, sudo if necessary.